# Subtract 2 times in react-native

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I want to subtract two times and check if check_in time > 12Hr then navigate to checkin screen. This is my code snippet

```
 class SplashView extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const curr_time = moment().format('hh:mm:ss');
        const checkin_time = moment(this.props.datetime).format('hh:mm:ss');
        // const diff = moment.duration(checkin_time.diff(curr_time));
        console.log("TIME&&&&&&&&", curr_time, checkin_time);
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.props.employee_id === null) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
            } else {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Checkin');
            }

        }, 1000)
    }



    render() {
        return ();
    }
}
```

I'm using moment.js and the value of this.props.datetime is '2019-02-04 14:52:01'. This is my checkin time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference in hours like this:

```
const diff = moment.duration(checkin_time.diff(curr_time)).as('hours');
```

Or you can just use moment's diff function

```
const diff = checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours')
```

and then compare `if (diff > 12) { ... }`

Comment: I'm getting an error " undefined is not a function (evaluating 'checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours')').

Comment: Try doing `checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours')` without formatting both the times in 'hh:mm:ss'

Comment: Error gone but I'm getting the output like this
 { _isAMomentObject: true,
      _isUTC: false,
      _pf: 
       { empty: false,
         unusedTokens: [],
         unusedInput: [],
         overflow: -2,
         charsLeftOver: 0,
         nullInput: false,

Comment: This is a moment object, what exactly are you logging? this? `console.log(checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours'))` This should print a number (in hours)

Comment: I'm getting it as 0

Comment: const curr_time = moment().format(); // '2019-02-04T16:59:44+05:30',
const checkin_time = moment(this.props.datetime).format(); //'2019-02-04T16:43:49+05:30'

These are the values of those two variables. How do I extract the time from both and find the difference to check whether the diff is > 12Hr

Comment: `console.log(checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours'))` This line is giving you the difference between two times in `hours`, just store it in a variable and see whether it is >12 or not. `if (checkin_time.diff(curr_time, 'hours') > 12) { /* hooray!! */ } `. The difference is 0 in hours between the times that you have provided